# AngularJs : How to get ng-repeat input/checkbox values on form submit?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

In my form there is input fields and check boxes that repeat as below.

```
<form class="form-horizontal popupform" novalidate>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="returns.altCity">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="returns.altZip">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="returns.altName">

 <table class="table table-striped">
       <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in order_items">
         <td>{{item.id}}</td>
         <td>{{item.price}}</td>
        <td>
           <input name="quantity-item.id"  type="number"
                  data-ng-model="item.quantity"
                   value="returns.id">
         </td>
         <td align="center">
             <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="item.checkOrder"
                checklist-value="returns.id" checked="checked">
                  <label>&nbsp;</label>
</td>
            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
 <button type="button" data-ng-click="saveReturnCases(returns)">Submit</button>

</form>
```

I want to get number input fields and check box values in button click. How can I get repeated field values?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the values in an array, use the $index value increameted by ngRepeat, and then, submit this array ($scope.quantities and $scope.checksOrder).

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="returns in item.order_items">
         <td>{{item.id}}</td>
         <td>{{item.price}}</td>
        <td>
           <input name="quantity-item.id"  type="number"
                  data-ng-model="quantities[$index]"
                   value="returns.id">
         </td>
         <td align="center">
             <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="checksOrder[$index]"
                checklist-value="returns.id" checked="checked">
                  <label>&nbsp;</label>
</td>
            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
 <button type="button" data-ng-click="saveReturnCases()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Hassein 
`<input name="quantity-item.id"  type="number"
                  data-ng-model="item.quantity"
                   value="returns.id">`
here this field should show value that load from the ng-repert. In ` data-ng-model="quantities[$index]"`  those value not show,  this is a number field so user can change the loaded value and submit

Comment: I do not understant the first value is defined by the value attribute in the input, so, it is returns.id, maybe I do not get your point ?